# How to blocking Button with Check button C# Forms Application

Tags: c#, forms

Hello i want to disable / enable button with check box.

myproject:

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please consider taking the [tour] and reading into [ask]. As is, your question lacks basic information that enables us to help you. Please go through above links and improve your question accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: I would recommend looking towards the event of a change in the state of checkbox: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checkedchanged?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly you question, there is a **property** called **Enabled** on the Control.
Here is a [link to that property documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.enabled?view=netframework-4.6.2)

**Update**: (Just to make more clear the answer based on comments)

It belogns to the `Winforms` API as this property is part of the  **Namespace** of `System.Windows.Forms`
As  most (if not every) control inherits from [Control Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control?view=netframework-4.6.2) and this Class has the **Enabled** property which states that *"Enabled 
Gets or sets a value indicating whether the control can respond to user interaction."*
So, every Control that inherits from this Class can use that property.

Comment: How do you know it's winforms?

Comment: When you open on the link I put it states:

Namespace: **System.Windows.Forms**
Assembly: System.Windows.Forms.dll

Comment: How do you know **OP** is about winforms?

Answer (score -1):

Hello if you want do get your button enabled or disabled try something like this.

first set the button.enable to false:

```
button.enabled = false;
```

then:

```
if(checkbox.checked == true)
{
 button.enabled = true;
}
else
{
 //let the user know with messagebox that he needs to accept the terms
}
```